# Does PHP make free stored result when closing prepared statement?

Tags: php

i am wondering what PHP is doing in this situation:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
$st = $mysqli->prepare('/* a query */');
$st->bind_param('','/* some values */');
$st->execute();
$st->store_result();
/* function using the stored result */
$st->close();
```

what PHP doing with the stored result?
where the stored result are saved temporary? (on MEMORY or HDD etc..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does PHP make free stored result when closing prepared statement?

**NO**, it stays in **memory** and you should use [free_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php) to free it.

```
$st->free_result();
$st->close();
```

---

(PHP 5)

`mysqli_result::free` -- `mysqli_free_result` — Frees the memory associated with a result.

**Note:**

> You should always free your result with mysqli_free_result(), when
>   your result object is not needed anymore.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php